# Threads and concurrency in populating struct in swift

Tags: swift

The problem I am facing here is that I want to populate/fill my filteredPosts with paginatedPosts. But when I try to do it and check the count it equals 0. I also tried to do it in viewWillApear but the situation is the same. As I understand it has something to do with threads and concurrency

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WelcomeScreen: UITableViewController, NetworkManagerDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    private var networkManager = NetworkManager()
    private var posts = [Article]()
    private var paginatedPosts: [Article] = []
    private var filteredPosts: [Article] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        filteredPosts = paginatedPosts
        print(filteredPosts.count)
        
        self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ArticleViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        
        searchBar.delegate = self
        
        networkManager.delegate = self
        networkManager.fetchNews("us")
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
        return filteredPosts.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard indexPath.row != posts.count - 1 else { return }
        if indexPath.row == paginatedPosts.count - 1 {
            let startIndex = paginatedPosts.count
            let endIndex = startIndex + 9
            
            if endIndex <= posts.count {
                paginatedPosts.append(contentsOf: posts[startIndex...endIndex])
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as?  ArticleViewCell else{
            return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
        
        let post = paginatedPosts[indexPath.row]
        cell.timePosted.text = post.publishedFormattedDateString
        cell.author.text = "by: \(post.author ?? "Author Unknown")"
        cell.title.text = post.articleDescription
        
        if let image = post.urlToImage {
            cell.imageForArticle.load(url: image)
        }
        
        return cell   
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let url = paginatedPosts[indexPath.row].url else{
            fatalError()
        }
        let webVC = WebViewController(url: url, title: paginatedPosts[indexPath.row].title)
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: webVC)
        navVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        present(navVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    func didUpdateNews(root: Root) {
        posts = root.articles
        
        paginatedPosts = posts.count >= 10 ? Array(posts[0...9]) : posts
        
        filteredPosts = paginatedPosts
    }
    
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        filteredPosts = []
        if searchBar.text == ""{
            filteredPosts = paginatedPosts
        } else {
            for item in posts{
                if ((item.articleDescription?.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text!)) != nil){
                    filteredPosts.append(item)
                }
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to change your `func didUpdateNews` to

```swift
func didUpdateNews(root: Root) {
    posts = root.articles
    
    paginatedPosts = posts.count >= 10 ? Array(posts[0...9]) : posts
   
    filteredPosts = paginatedPosts
    

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, and when I print filtered posts there are indeed 10 of them, but when I print them in viewdidload there is 0 of them

Comment: that's because you're initialising both as empty arrays:
`paginatedPosts: [Article] = [], filteredPosts: [Article] = []` and then calling `networkManager.fetchNews("us")` but result of this call is coming asynchronously, so until `didUpdateNews` will be called as a result of `fetch` you'll have empty array

Comment: Do not really understand, do I have to refactor my data somehow?

Comment: You can prefetch posts and on `viewDidLoad` take prefetched. Or you can make `fetch` synchronous but a `thread` will be blocked then, so it'd be not the best approach. The current approach with `asynchronous` call is fine, just update your data and `tableView` on getting a callback via `networkManager` delegate